# ProgressDialog is not showing when calling OKHttp request in Android

Tags: android, okhttp, android-webservice

While calling okhttp request, progressDialog not showing.I am showing the progress dialog before calling the request and dismiss the progress dialog after getting the repsonse. Here is the code.

```
progressDialog.show();
GetLogin logResp = new GetLogin();
      try {
           String response = logResp.run(Constants.LOGIN_URL +"username="+username+"&password="+password);
            if (response != null) {
               
                } catch(JSONException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }
            }else{
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    
    public class GetLogin {
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        String run(String url) throws IOException {
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(url)
                    .build();
    
            try (Response response = client.newCall(request).execute()) {
                return response.body().string();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you fix the code?

Comment: where are you calling progressDialog.show()?

Comment: Yes , I formatted the code. I call this progressDialog.show() before calling okhttp request